# How does a client in a wifi network validates the packet it recieves?

Tags: router, wireless, subnet, internet, mac-address

I have learnt that when a host in a wifi network receives a packet, it strips of the MAC address in the packet and verifies if that MAC address matches it's own MAC address and then only accepts the package. My Question is that- Where does this validation happen? Is it at NIC level or is it that all packets reach CPU and validation happen at CPU?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts or OSes are off-topic here, and how this works can vary by device and/or OS. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a host receives a frame, the **NIC generates an interrupt** for device driver and also does some filtering such as destination MAC address matches one of the interfaces or not, multicast address match etc.. The device driver handles the interrupt and allocates memory for the frame and sets the protocol for layer 2 and forwards it to the respective protocol handler.

So, the NIC does some level of packet filtering to reduce the overhead of CPU but the software also do such filtering as it does not depend solely on hardware for packet filtering.

In case promiscuous mode is ON for that interface, the check is ignored and all packets are accepted and traverse the network stack.

Comment: So, it happens via hardware i.e, a gate logic check on NIC? I mean to ask how does above filterations happens at NIC?

Comment: When you say, software also does such filterings, it should be CPU doing those checks right? because ultimately software runs on CPU only nah?

Comment: yes, this filtering is done at hardware level implemented through gated logic.

Comment: Here software means the network stack (starting from device driver). When software does packet filtering it is much extensive than that occurs at hardware level. and yes obviously it requires CPU. The hardware does some basic filtering which does not require CPU support.